# How do I generate multiple *different* random numbers?

Tags: python, list, random

I'm trying to create a code that produces a list of 5 different random number. Here is my current code:

```
import random

rN0 = random.randint(1, 50)
rN1 = random.randint(1, 50)
rN2 = random.randint(1, 50)
rN3 = random.randint(1, 50)
rN4 = random.randint(1, 50)

randomNumber = [rN0, rN1, rN2, rN3, rN4]
```

But, sometimes it produces two or more of the same number in the list. I would like each number in the list to be unique every time. Help please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `random.sample` that picks *n* random numbers from a given `range`:

```
>>> random.sample(range(1, 50), 5)
[4, 41, 16, 40, 25]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function to do just that:

```py
import random
def difRandom(min,max,amount):
  li=[]
  if amount>max+1-min:
    raise Exception("Not enough random numbers to cover amount. \nPlease increase max or decrease min.")
  for x in range(0,amount):
    r=random.randint(min,max)
    while r in li:
      r=random.randint(min,max)
    li.append(r)
  return(li)
```

All numbers will be different.

[Edit]

New function that is better:

```py
def difRandom(min,max,amount):
  li=[x for x in range(min,max+1)]
  final=[]
  if amount>max+1-min:
    raise Exception("Not enough random numbers to cover amount. \nPlease increase max or decrease min.")
  random.shuffle(li)
  for y in range(0,amount):
    final.append(li[y])
  return(final)
```

This function above is a bit quicker, and doesn't have to wait for the `random.randint` to get it right.

Comment: Note that the time complexity of such methods cannot be computed. It has the potential to be an endless loop.

Comment: Not so, the raise error stops that from being case of a user error.
However, I do agree that there is a slight chance, however small, that the random generator never generates a number to fill in the list. That is an extremely small chance though, and I have a feeling the random generator will generate the number before too long.

Comment: True, but I was talking about the behaviour of the `random` function. `randint` can return the "wrong" number for a very long time. Compare the performance of `difRandom(1, 100000, 100000)` with `random.sample`.

Comment: Yeah, true. The other way I could do it is generate a list of all the numbers in range, and then take a random out of those, deleting the random index every time. It would create an ever shortening list that never returns the some value, and doesn't have the same time problems.

Comment: This is a well researched subject. Look up "Fisher-Yates shuffle" if you are interested.

Comment: @Selcuk You act like your `random.sample` usage didn't have the exact same "problem"...

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode Well, because it doesn't. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @Selcuk , I have provided a solution in my edit, can you see any problems? Please tell me if you can.

Comment: @Selcuk It does pretty much [the exact same thing](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/854db7e82126701f2bf7a3ca0d78e3e26096aa75/Lib/random.py#L496-L503) here (except storing selected indexes in a set instead, but that's irrelevant for that "endless loop" issue).

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode The part you highlighted is only executed if `k` is relatively small when compared to `n`. See [this comment](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/854db7e82126701f2bf7a3ca0d78e3e26096aa75/Lib/random.py#L439-L444).

Comment: @Selcuk  As they are in your usage. I checked.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode It looks like you just want to nit pick and don't really want to have a technical argument. This is not the right place.

Comment: @AgentBiscutt Your second method is much faster as `shuffle` is `O(n)`. That being said, `random.sample` has a few more optimisations under the hood as can be seen from the source code linked above but your method is just fine for all practical purposes.

Comment: @Selcuk Your k would btw be even relatively smaller if you used the correct n (i.e., the correct range).

Comment: @Selcuk Ok, so [2.35 seconds is "much faster" than 0.53 seconds](https://tio.run/##zVLBasMwDL3nK0RPMc1CszIYhey26xi7diW4id0IbDm4zpZ@fWc7ydoNyq4LBFvSe0/ys7uTaw2tHzt7PqPujHVgOTVGJ42Q0KB8i1GRaqRM8yHj2vTk2CYBUFhud35FCWP2yQOWxZ2HhjJ4JTwKeB5q0Tk0lC5ejANBpj@0UxegXu@FPYIzUJsPYSelHN7pVQnu6Ui1jRsvDsZCI@YYKV8w30j67OBxQfMg0tX1jH6IcmyVhwXJzSdhsfrZohJgA1vhSPiLojDnXSeoSW1IWOF6S6lC9tOy@1uWDb8HnnDLggU3JRJX/8PYyYVj20upRDzi6Pbppttx@tkfhdvT7sqjWGRJIq0f0KEW6GB6dGOUBPHqIr6eVX1a9lSHyuVNZldmz1cH4KCc1FLF9b7hm0hNPfxh5X@WTd6UxSp87JvZ2XDXLov4vKqIa1FVY32ssfP5Cw). Good to know.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the below given code for this purpose :-

```
import random

#This code supposes that you need to generate 10 random integers.

randomNumber = random.sample(range(1, 50), 10)

#This function returns a list of random numbers within a given range 
#The second parameter tells how many random numbers to generate for the list
```